# Google-Cloud: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, tomcat8, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-spanner

Getting exception whilst using Google Pubsub to list topics, my web application is running on tomcat.

```
public static List<String> listTopics(GcpCredentials gcCredentials, String project) throws GCPException, IOException
{
    List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    TopicAdminClient client = getTopicClient(gcCredentials);
    ProjectName projectName = ProjectName.create(project);
    ListTopicsPagedResponse response = client.listTopics(projectName);
    for (Topic topic :response.iterateAll())
    {
        topics.add(topic.getNameAsTopicName().getTopic());
    }
    return topics;
}`
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
>       at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:174)
>       at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
>       at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:139)
>       at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:109)
>       at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiatorByType(NettyChannelBuilder.java:335)
>       at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:308)
>       at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DynamicNettyTransportParams.getProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:499)
>       at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:448)
>       at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:61)
>       at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:209)
>       at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.obtainActiveTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:186)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$SubchannelImplImpl.obtainActiveTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:806)
>       at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getTransportFromPickResult(GrpcUtil.java:568)
>       at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:296)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$5.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:724)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor.drain(ChannelExecutor.java:87)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl.runSerialized(ManagedChannelImpl.java:715)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl.onUpdate(ManagedChannelImpl.java:752)
>       at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:174)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I am facing the same issue with **Google Cloud Spanner**, could anyone please share anything that can help me.

Comment: The issue is an incompatibility between Tomcat and GRPC and [will be fixed](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2996) in future versions. The workaround detailed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921783/tomcat-and-grpc-both-upgrade-to-ssl) is to use grpc-java 1.4.0 which is compatible with netty-tcnative v2.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed this problem with Netty version 4.1.15.Final but not with 4.1.13.Final. Check your transitive dependencies. I.e Spring Boot references Netty.

What I added to POM to make it work with Spanner API version 0.22.0-beta:

`<properties>
     <v.netty>4.1.13.Final</v.netty>
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-handler-proxy</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-codec-socks</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
                <version>${v.netty}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`

If the problem persists, or if it is not an option, plase run your JVM with appropriate bootclasspath entry, like:

`java -Xbootclasspath/p:/tmp/alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar -cp ...`

Make sure to replace `/tmp/alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar` with location of alpn jar that **matches your JVM version** as listed on this page: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/alpn-chapter.html

Answer (score -1):

There is a possible solution on github: "[Exception when configuring SSL: "Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1311)"

The recommended steps, quoting from the above document:

1) Edit catalina.sh
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.3/libexec/bin/catalina.sh

2) At line 103, add the following
CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:/Library/Tomcat/lib/jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.6.jar"

3) Restart tomcat
../bin/shutdown.sh ../bin/startup.sh