# tomcat and grpc both upgrade to ssl

Tags: tomcat, ssl, grpc

i have a web application which deploy on tomcat 8 and this app also provide grpc service to other module, now i want to make the http service update to https and also the grpc should use ssl, but i have some issue on this job, the tcnative-1.dll is supported by tomcat to https, but grpc not use this, i used netty-tcnatice but it does't work in my tomcat, seems the two things can't work together,if i use tomcat's dll the grpc will pop up an error for not find the openssl install lib error:**Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.**
how could i do? please give some help, thanks.

Comment: in maven i use this jar:
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
   <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.33.Fork26</version>
   <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Tomcat incompatibility](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/136) is fixed with netty-tcnative 2. At the moment, you should use grpc-java 1.4.0 which is compatible with netty-tcnative v2.0.5.

Comment: yes,you are right.i upgrade the grpc version.it solved the problem for use new version of netty. thanks for your help!